# IQKeyboardManagerSwift, Use of unresolved identifier '_textField' ERROR

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, iqkeyboardmanager

When I imported `IQKeyboardManager` in Swift, I got this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier '_textField'

Anyone knows how to fix it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: _toolbarTintColor didn't find also.

Comment: Remove _ from the _textField and _toolbarTintColor and make it only  textField and  toolbarTintColor  because no need _ in swift 2.1

Comment: @Zealous Really?I will try it,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I updated IQKeyboardManager and it worked well. So I think it's a bug and they fixed it.